# WooCommerce Variations as Radio Buttons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

Is it possible within WooCommerce to change the variations dropdown into radio buttons without having to work with a plugin? I would like to have the following setup on the variations section:

- 1 liter (10€)
- 2 liter (20€)
- 3 Liter (25€)

The price at the bottom should be automatically changed when you select an option.

Comment: Would be nice to see an answer on this that isn't "go acquire another plugin".

Answer (score 40):

EDIT: added `variation_check()` and JS variation checking thanks to @ThomasB!

EDIT2: make sure `variation_check()` also checks for backorder status to allow selection when a product can be backordered.

The best way I managed to get this working is to add radio button markup directly after the select dropdowns and then hide the select dropdowns using CSS. You'll also need some custom JS to trigger the hidden select value changes so that your price will change according to the radio button you select.

Here's how I added the markup:

```php
function variation_radio_buttons($html, $args) {
  $args = wp_parse_args(apply_filters('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', $args), array(
    'options'          => false,
    'attribute'        => false,
    'product'          => false,
    'selected'         => false,
    'name'             => '',
    'id'               => '',
    'class'            => '',
    'show_option_none' => __('Choose an option', 'woocommerce'),
  ));

  if(false === $args['selected'] && $args['attribute'] && $args['product'] instanceof WC_Product) {
    $selected_key     = 'attribute_'.sanitize_title($args['attribute']);
    $args['selected'] = isset($_REQUEST[$selected_key]) ? wc_clean(wp_unslash($_REQUEST[$selected_key])) : $args['product']->get_variation_default_attribute($args['attribute']);
  }

  $options               = $args['options'];
  $product               = $args['product'];
  $attribute             = $args['attribute'];
  $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_'.sanitize_title($attribute);
  $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title($attribute);
  $class                 = $args['class'];
  $show_option_none      = (bool)$args['show_option_none'];
  $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __('Choose an option', 'woocommerce');

  if(empty($options) && !empty($product) && !empty($attribute)) {
    $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
    $options    = $attributes[$attribute];
  }

  $radios = '<div class="variation-radios">';

  if(!empty($options)) {
    if($product && taxonomy_exists($attribute)) {
      $terms = wc_get_product_terms($product->get_id(), $attribute, array(
        'fields' => 'all',
      ));

      foreach($terms as $term) {
        if(in_array($term->slug, $options, true)) {
          $id = $name.'-'.$term->slug;
          $radios .= '<input type="radio" id="'.esc_attr($id).'" name="'.esc_attr($name).'" value="'.esc_attr($term->slug).'" '.checked(sanitize_title($args['selected']), $term->slug, false).'><label for="'.esc_attr($id).'">'.esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name)).'</label>';
        }
      }
    } else {
      foreach($options as $option) {
        $id = $name.'-'.$option;
        $checked    = sanitize_title($args['selected']) === $args['selected'] ? checked($args['selected'], sanitize_title($option), false) : checked($args['selected'], $option, false);
        $radios    .= '<input type="radio" id="'.esc_attr($id).'" name="'.esc_attr($name).'" value="'.esc_attr($option).'" id="'.sanitize_title($option).'" '.$checked.'><label for="'.esc_attr($id).'">'.esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option)).'</label>';
      }
    }
  }

  $radios .= '</div>';
    
  return $html.$radios;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'variation_radio_buttons', 20, 2);

function variation_check($active, $variation) {
  if(!$variation->is_in_stock() && !$variation->backorders_allowed()) {
    return false;
  }
  return $active;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'variation_check', 10, 2);
```

And here's the JS I used:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.variation-radios input', function() {
  $('.variation-radios input:checked').each(function(index, element) {
    var $el = $(element);
    var thisName = $el.attr('name');
    var thisVal  = $el.attr('value');
    $('select[name="'+thisName+'"]').val(thisVal).trigger('change');
  });
});
$(document).on('woocommerce_update_variation_values', function() {
  $('.variation-radios input').each(function(index, element) {
    var $el = $(element);
    var thisName = $el.attr('name');
    var thisVal  = $el.attr('value');
    $el.removeAttr('disabled');
    if($('select[name="'+thisName+'"] option[value="'+thisVal+'"]').is(':disabled')) {
      $el.prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi cfx, Your code works perfect, but it adds radio buttons and don't remove default <select> element. Can You tell please, how to remove it and leave only radio buttons? Thank You :)

Comment: @Juraj I recommend that you hide the select element using CSS (it's part of my answer).

Comment: There is no way to remove it via hook?

Comment: @Juraj removing it altogether isn't a good idea because a lot of WooCommerce Product logic depends on the presence of the `<select>` element on variable product pages. The best way to get rid of it is to simply hide it with CSS unless you want to track down every line of code that depends on the element.

Comment: sadly doesn't work - if a variation is sold out, the radio will still be shown and active.

Comment: @ThomasB that doesn't mean that "it doesn't work," it's just been waiting for you to come along and help by providing a more ingenious, complete solution :)c

Comment: woooow @cfx your're the most positive person today. I admire you! :) <3
BTW: Still frigglin around and found no solution. Nearly about to go crazy or just keep ugly dropdowns. All those plugins... i dont like to use heavy weight plugins for simple stuff. so if you find a way, im totaly in to support the best way i can.

Comment: @ThomasB on my fresh Woo install, even with a dropdown, it still allows you to select the out of stock variation, but the ATC button is disabled. The result is similar with my solution and clicking on the OOS radio option keeps the ATC button disabled and even displays the OOS message.

Comment: @cfx your're absolutly right. But this just bad UX. Just because "it works" doenst mean "we should let the user use it". Just because the button is inactive after you've selcted a variation will leave you behind with question marks. I sadly found no solution to simply add special class "inactive" or something like that...

Comment: If you want to "greyish" and inactive the variation by default add this to your functions... pretty simple.

function yp_variation_check( $active, $variation ) {
 if( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
  return false;
 }
 return $active;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'yp_variation_check', 10, 2 );

Comment: @ThomasB heck yeah! That works well! I edited my solution to include that along with some JS to ensure the radio buttons are disabled as needed too!

Comment: @cfx OHBOYYY! That's why i love sof.... I told you, I admire you. Great solution now! I changed my code and will run this on production soon :) so much for love for you!

Comment: Thanks @ThomasB! It was a great collaboration. I did also just add one more tidbit in case the product can be backordered! :D

Comment: Awesome, thank you @cfx ! when I'm live i will add an tutorial to transform those bullets into color swatches without a plugin like yith. So we should have a nice collection over here afterwards.

Comment: Sorry @CFX I've broke it again :( I'n not fimiliar with JS thats my problem. I can work out the php and stylings.

I've added an ID, because we need the label-function for the color-swatches, as we hide the radio input itself. Now its not working anymore

    jQuery(element).removeAttr('disabled');
 /!   jQuery(element).removeClass('disabled');
    var thisName = $(element).attr('name');
...
      jQuery(element).prop('disabled', true);
/!      jQuery(element).addClass('disabled', true);
    }
 and in functions
<input type="radio" id="'.esc_attr($term->slug).'-'.esc_attr($name).'"

Comment: @ThomasB can you link to a gist with your complete code or post a new question?

Comment: https://codepen.io/thomasB88/pen/MWaKNpZ
I hope thats enough....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211823/discussion-between-cfx-and-thomasb).

Comment: plus 1 for not saying - use a plugin.

Comment: I added bit of JQuery to to remove property checked & remove inline css from the clear button :::        

 $("a.reset_variations").click(function(){
            $('input:radio[name="attribute_size"]').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).css('display', '');
        });

Comment: Is it possible to display only for particular product id.

Comment: @cfx, is there any way to check the variation's stock availability before adding it to the radio buttons?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do that without a plugin, but I suggest you drop that requirement, and use the [Woocommerce Radio Buttons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-variations-radio-buttons/) plugin. This does exactly what you want:

Comment: Looks like the plugin has not been updated for 2 years or more, and piles of unaswered support questions.

Comment: Try this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-variations-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Variation Swatches for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/) plugin. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I extended further the JavaScript part of cfx' answer to include cases of multiple variations. The idea is to hide and show available variations (radio buttons) based on the select inputs.

```js
<script>
    jQuery(document).on('change', '.variation-radios input', function() {
      jQuery('.variation-radios input:checked').each(function(index, element) {
        let el = jQuery(element);
        jQuery('select[name="' + el.attr('name') + '"]').val(el.attr('value')).trigger('change');
        recreateRadioInputs();
      });
    });
    
    jQuery(document).on('woocommerce_update_variation_values', function() {
      jQuery('.variation-radios input').each(function(index, element) {
        let el = jQuery(element);
        el.removeAttr('disabled');
        if(jQuery('select[name="' + el.attr('name') + '"] option[value="' + el.attr('value') + '"]').is(':disabled')) {
          $el.prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });
    });
    
    // recreate readio inputs based on the select inputs
    function recreateRadioInputs() {
        jQuery('.variation-radios input, .variation-radios label').hide();
        jQuery('.variations select').each(function() {
            let inputName = jQuery(this).attr('name');
            jQuery(this).find('option').each(function() {
                let inputVal = jQuery(this).val();
                let radioInput = jQuery('.variation-radios input[value="' + inputVal + '"]');
                jQuery('.variation-radios label[for="' + radioInput.attr('id') + '"]').show();
                radioInput.show();
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```