# Wrap every 2 differents elements inside specific div with wrapper class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, wrapall

I'am trying to wrap every two elements with my custom div.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="variation-radios">
    <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="60-cm">
    <label for="60-cm">60 cm</label>
    <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="70-cm">
    <label for="70-cm">70 cm</label>
    <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="80-cm">
    <label for="80-cm">80 cm</label>
    <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="90-cm">
    <label for="90-cm">90 cm</label>
</div>
```

And I want go get:

```
<div class="variation-radios">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="60-cm">
        <label for="60-cm">60 cm</label>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="70-cm">
        <label for="70-cm">70 cm</label>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="80-cm">
        <label for="80-cm">80 cm</label>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="90-cm">
        <label for="90-cm">90 cm</label>
    </div>      
</div>
```

The problem is that tehre are two diferent elements `label` and `input` and I can't add there a class. If there would be only inputs I could use jQuery wrapAll. But I don't know how to wrap completly two different html elements with jQuery.

Comment: I should say that for="" in a label should match the id of the related input. Your inputs should have ids. The labels should say for="(relevant id)".  THEN - Think of a single jquery selector that gets the pair together.

Comment: This is the reason why I trying to fix that with wrapper. Because it's woocommerce product page. I found the solution to convert option fields to radios from this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219833/woocommerce-variations-as-radio-buttons but for is not generated correctly. Works only for first group of radios.

Answer (score 2):

This code works like a champ:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="variation-radios">
    <input id="60-cm" type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="60-cm">
    <label for="60-cm">60 cm</label>
    <input id="70-cm" type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="70-cm">
    <label for="70-cm">70 cm</label>
    <input id="80-cm" type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="80-cm">
    <label for="80-cm">80 cm</label>
    <input id="90-cm" type="radio" name="attribute_pa" value="90-cm">
    <label for="90-cm">90 cm</label>
</div>

<script>
$('input').each(function() {
  $(this).add($(this).next('label')).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>')
});
</script>
```

It uses the `.each` method to loop through every `input` element, then add the next element: `label` to it, and then call the `.wrapAll` to wrap them both together with the div element.

Comment: Thanks Yishmeray!