# Woocommerce - empty images in product configurator

Tags: php, woocommerce, product-variations

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53073346/9598872), I have changed the default variation dropdown with options to radio buttons.
Then I bought product configurator plugin. My client want to achieve this result:

[image]

Every image in dropdown fired on hover on image below represents one radio button as variation.

I followed the instructions from plugin support:

[image]

I want to get images from configurator tab to frontend

[image]
[image]
[image]

So i tried this code:

```
// $product_id = 1645; // Replace with the ID of parent/variable product

$product_id = get_the_ID(); // getting current product ID
$images = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'jckpc_images', true );
// print_r( $images );

foreach ( $options as $option ) {

    $checked = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? checked( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : checked( $args['selected'], $option, false );
    $radios .= '<div class="moznost"><label><img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $images ) . '" width="80"><input type="radio" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" style="-webkit-appearance: none;" value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" id="' . sanitize_title( $option ) . '" ' . $checked . '></label></div>';                  
}
```

But I'm getting an empty (unknown) image URL:

[image]